# Accumulating prices for a time period?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, accumulate

I have this function and what I want is the `if`-statement to be run over and over, accumulating a a price until the conditions are no longer met.  Once met, do some other calculations in the `else`, reset the values (I tried with `= 0`) and return a value. But for some reason it doesn't do the right calculation and gives out nonsense.

```
cur_time = dt.datetime.now()
future_time = cur_time + 100

def A(cur_time, price):
    if int(future_time) > int(cur_time): 
        price_acum += (float(price))
    else:
        avg_price = price_acum/100
        print(avg_price )
        future_time = cur_time + 100
    return (avg_price )
```

Comment: How are you incrementing cur_time? Is there some loop that uses the function?

Comment: You should paste all relevant code. Where is price_acum getting initialized? Where is this function being called? Are you using a loop?

Comment: IF statements are executed only once. If you want to iterate until the condition is not satisfied then I guess you should write some loop statements like for or while.

Comment: Thanks, I simplified the code and accidentally delted "future_time = cur_time + 100"

Comment: `if int(future_time) > int(cur_time)` When would that ever _not_ be true?

Comment: `future_time = cur_time + 100` You can't add integers to datetime objects.  This is an error.  This code won't even run...